# How can I fix this Heroku deploy error with my .py and .env file?

Tags: python, heroku, deployment

I try to deploy my files with Heroku and Github.
I upload a .py and a .env file to Github and connect it with Heroku. After that I deploy the branch manual.
I get this error and I don't know how to fix this.

````
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Using buildpacks:
       1. heroku/python
       2. https://github.com/niteoweb/heroku-buildpack-shell.git
-----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz
       More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
 !     Push failed```
````

Comment: Hi, you should take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) on StackOverflow, explaining how to properly ask a question. The community is here to help you, but you definitely need to provide more details to help us answer your question :)

Comment: Have you looked at the page the error suggests looking at?

Answer (score 0):

```
-----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz
       More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
```

Your Python buildpack is not compatible.

The [info](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure) says:

> If the configured buildpack cannot handle your application (as determined by its [detection script](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpack-api#bin-detect)), you will receive an error.

The Python buildpack can be found here: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python

The `bin/detect` script says:

```
BUILD_DIR=$1

# Exit early if app is clearly not Python.
if [ ! -f "$BUILD_DIR/requirements.txt" ] && [ ! -f "$BUILD_DIR/setup.py" ] && [ ! -f "$BUILD_DIR/Pipfile" ]; then
  exit 1
fi

echo Python
```

In order for the `bin/detect` script to pass it requires a `requirements.txt`, `setup.py` or `Pipfile` at the root of your git repository. That's missing.

Comment: What should i write in the "requirements.txt" file I am somehow not so sure about it?

Comment: Your Python project probably depends on outside libraries. These libraries you put into `requirements.txt`. You can also create that file with `python -m pip freeze > requirements.txt` It could also be `python3`, `py`, or `py3`.

Comment: Please set the question as solved. Thank you.